# Random order in bluebird's 'each' function

Tags: node.js, bluebird

I have array 'results' of messages from database, and now I want to add nickname to this message also from database. Array that I'am receiving from database is sorted by date, but when i use this code, results are in kind of random order.

```
Promise.each(results, function(message) {
    users.db.find({id64: message.id64}).then(function(user) {
        message.nick = user[0].nick;
        socket.emit('chat message toClient', message);
    })
})
```

I may approach this from the wrong side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need a return keyword before users.db...

Comment: Haha thank you! Just one word... I now understand how it works.

Answer (score 0):

By design doing an asynchronous operation on sorted data will not produce results in the same order. You can re-sort by date on the other end, or not try to do things asynchronously.

Synchronous:

```
results.forEach(results, function(message) {
    users.db.find({id64: message.id64}).then(function(user) {
        message.nick = user[0].nick;
        socket.emit('chat message toClient', message);
    })
})
```